# Try to build search filter in react-redux

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to create search with react redux but i am confuse how it works with map data.
so here is my code:
searchaction.js

```js
export const SEARCH = 'SEARCH'
const search = (term) => {
    return {
        type:SEARCH,
        term
    }
}
```

searchreducer.js:

```js
import {SEARCH} from '../searchaction'
// import {games} from './games'
export const searchreducer = (state = '', action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case SEARCH:
            return action.term
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

rootreducer.js

```js
import {combineReducers} from  'redux';

import {games} from './reducers/games';
import {searchreducer} from './reducers/searchreducer';

export default combineReducers({
    games,
    search:searchreducer
});
```

gamelist.js in which i am getting data from api:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchReport from './reportsearch';
// import {deleteReports} from './actions';

export const GamesList = ({games, deleteReports}) => {
   const emptyMessage = (
       <p>There are no games yet in your collection.</p>
   )
   const gamesList = (
       
    <div className="row">
 
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Registraton date</th>
    <th>Registraton No</th>
    <th>Paitient Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Refer By</th>
    <th>Test Requested</th>
    <th>Report Status</th>
    <th>Total Amount</th>
    <th>Receipt Amount</th>
    <th>Balance Amount</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   
          {games.map((reports,i) =>  
                <tbody key={i}>            
             <tr>
             <td>{reports.reg_date}</td>
             <td>{reports.reg_no}</td>
             <td>{reports.patient_name}</td>
             <td>{reports.gender}</td>
             <td>{reports.age}</td>
             <td>{reports.refer_by}</td>
             <td>{reports.test_request}</td>
             <td>{reports.report_status}</td>
             <td>{reports.total_amt}</td>
             <td>{reports.receipt_amt}</td>
             <td>{reports.bal_amt}</td>
             <td><Link to={`/games/${reports.r_id}`} id={reports.r_id} className="btn-floating btn-large blue"><i class="large material-icons">edit</i></Link></td>
             <td><button className="btn-floating btn-large red" onClick={() => deleteReports(reports.r_id)} deleteReports={deleteReports}><i class="large material-icons">delete</i></button></td>
             </tr>             
</tbody>
          )}          
            </table>
          </div>
        )
          return (
         <div>
          
         {games.length === 0 ? emptyMessage : gamesList}
         </div>
    )
}

GamesList.propTypes = {
    games: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    deleteReports: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

gamepage.js where i am rendering components gamelist.js and searchreport:

```js
class GamesPage extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchGames();
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Report List</h1>
               <SearchReport />
            <GamesList games={this.props.games} deleteReports={this.props.deleteReports}  />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

GamesPage.propTypes = {
    games: PropTypes.array.isRequired ,
    fetchGames: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteReports: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        games:state.games
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchGames, deleteReports} )(GamesPage)
```

thats my code i am confuse how this map data will connect with search input and filter it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: that's a lot of code to read without a specific programming question.  can you tell us what specific point in the code is not doing what you want?  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: when i am type in input field the state changes but data coming from game.map is not getting change

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [selector](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html). So basically:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        games: getSearchResults(state)
    }
}
```

getSearchResults can just filter the array directly or enhance it with the reselect library mentioned in the documentation. But that would be more of an implementation detail. Here an example of just a filter:

```
const getSearchResults = (state) => {
  return state.games.filter((game) => game.includes(state.search)
}
```